# Rails dealing with blank params at controller level

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  # validation lets users update accounts without entering password
  validates :password, presence: { on: :create }, allow_blank: { on: :update }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: { if: :password_digest_changed? }
end
```

I also have a **password_reset_controller**:

```
def update
  # this is emailed to the user by the create action - not shown
  @user=User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    # user is signed in if password and confirmation pass validations
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset."
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong, please try again."
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Can you see the problem here? A user can submit a blank a password/confirmation and rails will sign them in, because the User model allows blank on update.

It's not a security concern, since an attacker would still need access to a user's email account before they could get anywhere near this action, but my problem is that a user submitting 6 blank chars would be signed in, and their password would not be changed for them, which could lead to confusion later on.

So, I've come up with the following solution, and I'd like to check if there's a better way of doing it, before I push to production:

```
def update
  @user=User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])

  # if user submits blank password, add an error, and render edit action     
  if params[:user][:password].blank?
    @user.errors.add(:password_digest, "can't be blank.")
    render :edit
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset."
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong, please try again."
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Should I be checking for nil as well as blank? Are there any rails patterns or idiomatic ruby techniques for solving this?

[Fwiw, I've got `required: true` on the html inputs, but want this handled server side too.]

Comment: Just to clarify, a user can't create a new account with a blank password right?  Only on update they can currently have a blank password & password confirmation which you want to prevent, correct?

Comment: yeah, only on update, and it doesn't change their password digest at all

Comment: Why are you allowing them to save a blank password on update?  Why not just remove allow_blank?

Comment: If I do that, then they will need to enter their password anytime they want to edit their user account (if they want to change their name, email address etc). Allow blank is useful in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

we can use - **present?**

Ex:

```
if !params[:user][:password].present?
```